# PSexec file on list of computers speed up

Tags: batch-file, cmd, psexec

I was hoping I could have some help with this. I have about 300 computers that I have to clear all the temporary internet folders on and separately do a logoff on them.

Currently I have a file located on the C: drive that has the following command:

- Clear temporary internet folders:

  ```
  RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255
  ```
- log off

  ```
  shutdown /l /t 0 /f
  ```

Here is the PSexec command I use to remotely execute that command on every computer:

```
@echo off

psexec @C:\_\complist.txt -u Admin -p PASSWORD -i.    c:\clearcache.cmd
```

The problem I am having is that it is taking really long, about 30 - 35 minutes because it does one at a time. Is there anyway I can speed this up? Maybe instead of doing 1 at a time I can do all at once?

If anyone can help improve the speed or help me find a better way I would be so grateful.

Thanks

Error I am getting when executing:
[image: Execute error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the other way round: instead of doing all at once, do them separately. Sounds contraproductive? Parse `complist.txt` with batch and start `psexec` for each single computer instead of a list of computers:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\_\complist.txt) do (
  start "%%i" psexec \\%%i -u Admin -p PASSWORD -i.  c:\clearcache.cmd
)
```

`start` creates a new process for executing `psexec` on every single computer and doesn't wait for it to finish, so they all run (nearly) parallel.

Comment: What does it mean to parse complist.txt with batch? sorry I am a beginner at this. every which way I try to run the code it pops up with several screens but never executes the code.

Comment: parsing means basically reading the file line by line. The `for` construct assigns each line of the textfile to the variable `%%i` (one after the other). You can then do something with `%%i` (in other words: do the same thing with every line)

Comment: oh ok got ya - so I don't have to do anything to the actual complist.txt, if I understand correctly. So when I execute the script you wrote above - it doesn't actually execute the script on the computer itself . See the picture I took when running the script.

Comment: I have no `psexec` installed, so I can't try. But the dot after `/i` looks quite suspicious to me. May that lead to a syntax error?

Comment: would there be a better way other than using psexec?

Comment: @swstrau118 there should not be a period in your code. Does the batch file exist in the root of the C: drive on each computer?

Comment: The switch is `-i` to run the command interactively, think CMD.exe not a script so it's not needed in my opinion.

Comment: @Squashman II got it to work.. for the comp list I had \\HOSTNAME\c$ but I changed it to only show the hostname and now it works perfectly. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at SCCM to run a script like this, lot of overhead if its not in place yet. But could be worth looking at for larger deployments in the future.

I have used PDQ Deploy in the past works well, they have a few levels of licensing including a free one depending on your business. [DPQ Modes](http://www.adminarsenal.com/deploy-what-is-pro-mode/)

Also have you considered pushing out a scheduled task that clears the IE favorites on a set date, this could also run the log off command but that could get messy. With a scheduled task in place could just run the log off command like you have in the past which wont be waiting for the clean command to finish.

If you have a domain you can use Group Policy to push out the scheduled task to the PCs saving you from making a import script and deploying that with psexec.exe.

Just a few Ideas for you.